# Gram Schmidt procedure

Tags: linear-algebra, gram-schmidt

[image]

For the subspace on the left in the image I am to find an orthogonal basis for the subspace. The answer is to the right in the image, and when I follow the procedure I get those vectors, however I also get one vector to be (0, 0, -120/15, 0). Why is that not included in the basis?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to find an orthogonal basis for the subspace spanned by the vectors on the left (which is $3$-dimensional)? Or the orthogonal complement (which is $1$-dimensional)?

Comment: Sorry, I should say orthogonal basis for the subspace!

Comment: OK, then you made a mistake. You should not be able to get $4$ vectors.

Comment: If I update the question with a description of the procedure our particular textbook uses, could it have something to do with the last part, where they write "w3 was already in S2" does that reasoning somehow apply to this problem?

Comment: That is the precise reasoning.

Comment: How do they see that w3 was in S2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the third step, $\mathbb{S}_2=\mathrm{span}\{v_1,v_2\}$ also equals $\mathbb{S}_2=\mathrm{span}\{w_1,w_2\}$. The Gram-Schmidt process produces a vector $v_3=\mathrm{perp}_{\mathbb{S}_2}w_3\in \mathbb{S}_2^\perp$ with $\mathrm{span}\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}=\mathrm{span}\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$. Since $v_3=0$, 
$$
\mathrm{span}\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}=\mathrm{span}\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}=\mathrm{span}\{v_1,v_2,0\}=\mathrm{span}\{v_1,v_2\}=\mathrm{span}\{w_1,w_2\}.
$$
Therefore, $w_3\in\mathrm{span}\{w_1,w_2\}=\mathbb{S}_2$.

Comment: Thank you David! Is this just because w3 gives the zero vector and therefore can be left out? Im guessing not because then why would (0,0,-120,0) from the example not be in the basis? If you are tired of explaining thank you for your time!

Comment: I think you mean $v_3$. Also, you must have made a mistake in your calculation.

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake somewhere. The four original vectors span a $3$-dimensional space and therefore there is no way of obtaining a basis with $4$ elements. Exactly *which* error you made is something I cannot tell you without seeing your computations.

Comment: Hello, Jose. I updated my question after the first post as I wrote the question incorrectly. I am trying to compute the orthogonal basis.

Comment: I see no reason to change my answer.